# Can't install Gnome Shell extensions via browser

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I usually install extensions for the GNOME Shell by visiting [GNOME Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) in firefox, then clicking the ON/OFF button on the page for the extension I'd like to install. In Ubuntu, this works. In my fresh Debian 9 installation, however, clicking the button seems to have no effect. It switches to ON and I am asked for confirmation, though. But when I reload the page, the switch shows OFF. This does not work in Chromium, either.

Comment: Does this happen with some specific extension(s) or all extensions?

Comment: With all extensions. I got some extensions via the package `gnome-shell-extensions` in the official repository, so I can turn at least these on and off. @pomsky

Comment: I installed the chrome integration package, it doesnt show up in chrome.  Same problem?